# Is there a difference between JavaScript and Unity JavaScript (UnityScript)?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm going to start scripting in Unity3D pretty soon for game development using UnityScript (since I am a beginner). If I had experience in JavaScript (which I don't), will I find UnityScript any different? If so, how much of a difference is there between these two scripting languages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can JavaScript be expressly used to develop Unity games?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809074/can-javascript-be-expressly-used-to-develop-unity-games)

Answer (score 6):

This is summed up in the [unityscript](/questions/tagged/unityscript) tag wiki here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info

Main differences:

- UnityScript has classes, JS has no concept of classes (yet)
- The filename of a UnityScript automatically puts the code in a class of that same name (minus the extension)
- No global variables in UnityScript
- In UnityScript, `this` is always the class pointer (aka `self`)

Specifically this link tells you all about the differences between JS and US:
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript