# How to add javaScript Tag Unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

i want to implement ads for web application. so i just want to know how to implement and execute this type of javascript tag in unity.

```js
<!-- BEGIN JS TAG - Mobi2Fun_468x60 < - DO NOT MODIFY -->

<SCRIPT SRC="http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=5917312&cb=[CACHEBUSTER]" TYPE="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>

<!-- END TAG -->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can JavaScript be expressly used to develop Unity games?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809074/can-javascript-be-expressly-used-to-develop-unity-games)

Comment: There is a lot of plugins for unity to add ADS. When you talk web application you mean WebGL or UnityPlayer? BTW if current available ADS plugins doesn't fit your needs you can do whatever you want outside the game as you'll embbed your game into a common webpage but you need to pay attention on ADS rules about this kind of link...

Comment: just use it in the html file that unity creates